# UITableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier returns nil with VoiceOver on iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, voiceover

I am having some trouble with VoiceOver turned on starting in iOS 7. I did register an instance of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` child class inside `viewDidLoad` but when I am dequeque-ing it with `-[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:]` it is always returning `nil` object.

The issue started to appear on iOS 7.0. It was not there on the previous version and certainly it works fine if it runs perfectly without VoiceOver on both 6.0 and 7.0

I could just not having a custom header instead, or instantiate a new object when `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:` returns nil. But I was wondering whether there is a known issue regarding this.

Cheers,

Comment: did you get any more info on this? for me, it's not returning nil ever, even the first time it hits dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:, instead it returns the tableviewheader with frame (0,0,0,0)

Comment: One of my colleague talked to an Apple Developer during one of the Tech Talks and they said that there might be some problem with that and they re looking into it :)

In the end, when I did get nil, I just instantiate the view from the NIB and return that instead.

Comment: I think loading the nib yourself and returning the cell object is your best option. I just hit this today, and it looks like the header cell's init/initWithFrame is being called, which ignores the nib file. So, you end up with a cell that has none of its outlets connected.

Comment: @ScottK. That is interesting. Why would the framework call initWithFrame instead of initializing it from the nib

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like something in the accessibility support is calling cell.view, which will use the default initializer for the registered class. That calls through to init, which calls initWithFrame.

Comment: @Rpranata Had u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to create custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

```
(void)registerClass:(Class)aClass forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```